# DataAdapter updated field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i am trying to update my table from a gridview, the code below shows me no errors but my tables doesnt update, what is the idea for my mistake?

**new updated** for the pageload, the loadstatement is work,i able to fill the data into my datagridview but i still cannot update my database wuth my button clicks. the problems remain, no errors is throws. but no update

```
   void LoadStatement()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, sqlConn))
            {
                dtbl = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dtbl);

                dgv1.DataSource = dtbl;
            }
        }

    }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string updCommand = "Update Salary set Salary = "+ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Salary"].ToString()+"";
            SqlCommand sqlcmdUpd = new SqlCommand(updCommand, conn);


            da.UpdateCommand = sqlcmdUpd;

            sqlcmdUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();    


            SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            da.Update(ds,sTable);

            lblErrorMsg.Text = "Updated";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: why are you making  sqlcmdUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();    and then Update()?

Comment: i just trying around, both way doesnt works =(

Comment: Could you please share your connection string structure ?

Answer (score 0):

**Never code like that!**

Always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This code is open for an [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
string updCommand = "Update Salary set Salary = @Salary";
SqlCommand sqlcmdUpd = new SqlCommand(updCommand, conn);
sqlcmdUpd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Salary"].ToString());
sqlcmdUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This codes looks fine. Check your `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Salary"].ToString()` varabile again, and please debug your code and look all variables is what you want or not..

Try to use your `DataAdapter` like;

```
DataAdapter da = new DataAdapter(sqlcmdUpd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: @CheemunLow Did you debug your code? Did you check all variables? Something should wrong because this code looks fine to me..

Comment: Hi soner, my ds get all the result correctly, maybe my dataAdapter doesnt help me to update my dataset to datatable, i am not sure, but then there are no any errors mention to me

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Salary"].ToString() got the value that i want, variables work fine =(

Answer (score 0):

Are you only operating with 1 table only?

I don't think you need all those code. Try this:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    da.Update(ds,sTable);

    lblErrorMsg.Text = "Updated";
}
```

Any changes on the DataGrid should be saved correctly to the database.